# Chart.js Straight Line Between Zero Values

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart to show increases and decreases of an average rate. I have the chart set up how I need other than there is a negative fill in-between two zero values. This is because of the curvature of the entire line. I would like a way to be able to have any bit of the line that starts and ends with a zero value to be flat. Below you can see that my issue is between the months August and September.

The only options I have been able to find so far is to change the line to be straight in-between all points but I dont want that.

My Chart:

[image]

Here is the `JS` that changes the color depending on y position:

```
plugins: [{
        beforeRender: function (x, options) {
            var c = x.chart
            var dataset = x.data.datasets[0];
            var yScale = x.scales['y-axis-0'];
            var yPos = yScale.getPixelForValue(0);

            var gradientFill = c.ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, c.height);
            gradientFill.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(42, 212, 137,.5)');
            gradientFill.addColorStop(yPos / c.height - 0.001, 'rgba(42, 212, 137,.5)');
            gradientFill.addColorStop(yPos / c.height + 0.001, 'rgba(239, 41, 41,.5)');
            gradientFill.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(239, 41, 41,.5)');

            var model = x.data.datasets[0]._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].dataset._model;
            model.backgroundColor = gradientFill;
        }
    }]
```